# Is It Possible to use Laravel 4 without a Default Database

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4

I'm creating an application that reads information from a number of different databases, but doesn't actually have its own database, as there is no information being written anywhere.

Basically, a user selects a record and a type, and the application will generate a `.pdf` file based on their choices. I have multiple connections defined in `app/config/database.php` but I don't want to connect to any of them by default. Is there a way to tell Laravel *not* to connect to a database? I've tried a few things (all in `app/config/database.php`), first being:

```
'default' => NULL,
// and 
//'default' => '',
```

Which both return:

> Undefined index: driver

I've also tried:

```
'default' => 'none',

'connections' => array(
    'none' => array(
        'driver' => '',
        'host' => '',
        ...
     ),
 ),
```

which in turn returns:

> Unsupported driver []
>
> Unsupported host[]
>
> ...

And lastly setting `'default' => ''`, which returns:

> Database [] not configured.

I've found ways to use Laravel's models without a database connection, but not actually Laravel itself.

**Edit**:

Setting the connection to an existing mysql connection and not selecting a database "works":

```
'default' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => '',
    'username'  => '****',
    'password'  => '****',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

but I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it. It feels like a work-around and not an actual solution.

Comment: Create your own driver that does nothing?

Comment: As long as you don't use it, it won't do anything, so just leave it alone.

Answer (score 5):

I would do the following:

```
'driver' => 'sqlite',
```

and for the `sqlite` connection settings

```
'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => ':memory:',
    'prefix' => '',
]
```

That way, it'll use an [in-memory database](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) and the database will cease to exist when the database connection is closed, and since you won't be opening a connection, you'll never have a local database open.

You could also remove the database service provider from your `app.php` config file:

```
    'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
    //'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
```

and the facades for Fluent and Eloquent in the same file:

```
    'Crypt'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
    //'DB'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
    //'Eloquent'  => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
    'Event'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
```

which will prevent you from being able to connect to local databases and not even boot the `sqlite` database connection you've just set up.

Comment: Returns an error, just like I stated on the last question that suggested `sqlite` as my driver: `"PDOException: could not find driver"` (answer was deleted by poster, but was essentially the same as yours). Also, I still am using the `DB` and `Eloquent` facades, as in I'm still pulling information from a database, so the second half of your question seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah the second part was more for if people revisited the question and wanted an app without a database.

Just out of interest, what environment are you using to run your code? I use sqlite in memory databases all the time for tests and have never encountered an issue with not being able to find the drivers.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, but it's not applicable to what I'm trying to do :P Also, working on Linux Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache/MySql/PHP 5.4 (I think)

Comment: I've just tried this solution but found out that you can just set ** 'default' => false ** in the database config, and then comment out the lines you mentioned (service provider and facades), and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do define the connection in the app/config/database.php file and specify the connection when running a query with laravel's DB::connection('connection_name'). 
More information here --> http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#accessing-connections

Comment: I've done that with all of the above methods. The only one where it worked is with the final no-database example. The other three were still causing the same error(s). Accessing my `Route::get("/")` called `DB::connection("example")...` (which was not the default database) and still failed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define your db driver as 'sqlite' in the database config.

```
'default' => 'sqlite',
```

As long as you haven't changed anything in the default sqlite config section, all should work. You don't necessarily have to use the database, but it will alleviate those errors you received.

In case you have changed the default sqlite config for whatever reason, you can follow the below steps to configure the sqlite db.

```
'sqlite' => array(
    'driver'   => 'sqlite',
    'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
    'prefix'   => '',
),
```

Also, make sure this 'production.sqlite' file exists if it doesn't already. You can do this easily from the command line:

```
touch app/database/production.sqlite
```

Comment: Returns: `"PDOException: could not find driver"`. See Andrew Willis` answer.